# What do I do to rectify the FutureBuilder part of the code?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run this part of the code only the snapshot.hasError part keeps getting executed. I'm not sure which part of it went wrong. So could anyone please help me with that?
Thanks in advance!!

**FutureBuilder part of the code:**

```
 Widget futureData(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZCv1LyQUyAJQE21-uNUMx3S8ZgK2U9S--1wQB59QaTFHBp2VqxGTAen5FRA7m5h-E4OU&usqp=CAU'),
              fit: BoxFit.contain)),
      // child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Center(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      gapPadding: 3.0,
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        width: 2.0,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11)),
                  hintText: 'search',
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.search_sharp,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: InkWell(
                    child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next, color: Colors.grey),
                    onTap: () => getInfo(),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _info,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text("failed"));
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Text("data");
                }
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: 1,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                firstrow(),
                                SizedBox(height: 10),
                                secondrow(),
                                SizedBox(height: 2),
                                thirdrow(),
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                                fourthrow(),
                                fifthrow(),
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                                sixthrow(),
                                SizedBox(height: 10),
                                weatherList(),
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                              ],
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }
```

**Code for parsing the data:**

```
    TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
 late Future _info;
  late DataModel dataModel;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _info = getInfo();
  }

  Future<DataModel> getInfo() async {
    http.Response data = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${_textEditingController.text}&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=3c044b7295d2df14f8bee74c19d4b96f'));
    if (data.body != null) {
      print("object " + data.body.toString());
      dataModel = DataModel.fromJson(json.decode(data.body));
    }
    return dataModel;
  }
```

When I run this code, the data is getting displayed in the console but on the UI screen, the snpashot.hasError part is being returned. How do I get that data displayed on my screen successfully?

Comment: Please check your DataModel.fromJson(json.decode(data.body)). Looks like you have an error in parsing data.

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder uses an Future instance, but your getInfor() method does not return a future.
I advice defining the return type of the method as Future.

```
Future<DataModel> getInfo() async {
...
}
```

then in your widget class:

- define a Future instance to receive the data returned by the getInfo() method.
  Future _info;
- inside the initState(), initialize the variable by assigning it the method returned info.

  ```
  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _info = getInfo();
  }
  ```

then inside your futureBuilder widget you would call the Future instance:

```
  FutureBuilder(
        future: _info,
        ...
```

I advice setting the getInfo() method in a different file (you would call it api_manager.dart)

Comment: I have made the changes that you mentioned but it's still the same. I'm getting the data in the console but not on the UI.

Comment: Please set your builder like this: `builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Welcome> snapshot) ` . then let me know.